# How to generate XML from relational data (CSV)?

Tags: xml, csv, xsd

What is the best approach that we can use for XML generation for the below need?

I have data in (comma delimited file / relational DB / text) and XSD for XML structure, and I need to generate an XML by mapping them together.  How can I write the rules on where the data elements has to map for structure?

Answer (score 0):

1. Export your data to CSV.
2. Use Andrew J Welch's [CSV to XML converter in XSLT 2.0](http://andrewjwelch.com/code/xslt/csv/csv-to-xml_v2.html) to generate a basic XML representation of your data.
3. Write XSLT to map from your basic XML representation to the XML called for by your XSD.